# What would be the regex expression for this situation?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex challenge for you (I need you help)

I'm trying to make a regex that **finds "bbb" only if "aaa" is not present between the beginning of the string and the "bbb" word**.

So I built the following expression: **`^(?!.*(aaa)).*?(bbb)`**

It works but I noticed that "bbb" is not found when "aaa" is located after "bbb"... I need the expression to **find "bbb" even if "aaa" is located between "bbb" and the end of the string**.

So:

Must find "bbb" in:

```
"ddd bbb eee"
"bbb fff aaa"
```

Must **not** find "bbb" in:

```
"aaa bbb eee ddd" 
"aaa ccc bbb"
```

Ps: See this link (select Java) http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgIDii-WPCgw/index.html to test the regex.
I simplified the test strings for my case but just so you know, in real life those strings will be actual various sentences.

Thank you

EDIT:

Awwhh man! I always forget something in my regex questions! Loll

I forgot to mention that "bbb" needs to be replaced (replaceAll) by another word (ie: "zzz"). So the result of the expression needs to be a modified string and not a boolean.

So we should have these results:

```
"ddd bbb eee" => "ddd zzz eee"
"bbb fff aaa" => "zzz fff aaa"
"bbb ggg bbb" => "zzz ggg zzz"
"aaa bbb eee ddd" => "aaa bbb eee ddd"
"aaa ccc bbb" => "aaa ccc bbb"
"fff aaa eee bbb jjj bbb" => "fff aaa eee bbb jjj bbb"
```

Sorry I could not update the test link from my mobile.

Comment: Try `^(?:(?!\baaa\b).)*\bbbb\b`

Comment: Further to @Thefourthbird's comments, the "Tempered Greedy Token" is discussed [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Comment: @Thefourthbird, if the string may contain newlines and the restriction applies only when `aaa` and `bbb` are in the same line, a slight variant may be appropriate: `^(?:(?!\baaa\b|\n).)*\bbbb\b`.

Comment: I forgot to mention something, please see my edited question.

Comment: Use a capturing group `^((?:(?!\baaa\b).)*?)\bbbb\b` and in the replacement use `$1zzz` See https://regex101.com/r/DsVBVO/1

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird ! Your solution worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

It's almost correct!!

Jus a small correction: `String pattern = "^(?!.*(aaa).*?(bbb))";`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] lines =  {"ddd bbb eee",
                           "bbb fff aaa",
                           "aaa bbb eee ddd",
                           "aaa ccc bbb"};

        String pattern = "^(?!.*(aaa).*?(bbb))";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);


        for (String line: lines)
        {
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
            System.out.println(matcher.find());
        }
    }
```

**O/p:**

```
True
True
False
False
```

Hope this works..

Comment: You have my vote. But please try to use word boundaries as it makes the regex more failproof. Something like `^(?!.*?(\baaa\b).*?(\bbbb\b))`

Comment: Your regex fails to match the string `bbb aaa bbb`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/nvxuP9/1/)

Comment: I'm not sure in that case whether it should allow or not. :| It neither satisfies not dissatisfies the req.

Comment: I forgot to mention something, please see my edited question.